# How can/should Zend Framework 2 be included to a Git versioned project?

Tags: git, version-control, zend-framework2

How should the version controlling of a Zend Framework 2 project be managed? Is there a best practice / "standard approach" for this? Is "submodule" the right keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Zend Framework 2 Project is usually a lightweight skeleton application with various installed modules, which usually are on separate dedicated repositories.

The main repository isn't usually affected by many changes, so you can create a git repository (fork of [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)) for it. While the modules are more relevant and require some care, the skeleton application usually changes only in a couple details over the months.

I can suggest following approach:

1. create your first versions of the app-specific modules as [git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) in the `modules/` directory of your skeleton application fork.
2. work on the modules in the suggested way, by simply committing back to the original repositories and updating the git submodule references in the root repository.
3. Once you have a fairly well working version (and have some confidence with [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) and zf2 in general), you can convert them into composer packages by adding a [`composer.json`](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) file.
4. Remove the git submodule of the converted zf2 module and [use composer to import it](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) instead. To do so, you will simply need to tell composer where the repository is located. This will make the module installable in seconds on any of your applications, helping you in re-using existing components. Re-using code you wrote for different projects becomes really easy from now on.
5. tag and progressively stabilize dependencies and versions of your packages (because you will start to have your own [private composer packages ecosystem](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md))

This is how I personally do it, and it has turned into a very nice development process. Each time a feature is shared, I simply move it to a new package and update the `composer.json` in the modules. [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) takes care of the rest, and all our live systems are very fast to upgrade.

You may want to read some more [advanced techniques and tips and tricks about composer](http://www.naderman.de/slippy/src/?file=2012-11-22-You-Thought-Composer-Couldnt-Do-That.html) once you are familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! How do you include the [Framework folder](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) to a project? Currently it's just a subfolder in my project-repo. Should it be a submodule?

Comment: @automatix the framework is installed via composer too. If you cloned the skeleton application, it's just a matter of running `php composer.phar install` :)

Comment: Hm... You are right. :) The last question to this toptic: If a further library is added (to `/vendor/`), it can be managed with composer too, right? Are there other possibilities to manage libraries?

Comment: Yes, packages are usually libraries. It really is just a matter of getting used to it. Once you grasped the basics of composer, it will be much more clear.

Comment: I think you are right, I should strat with the composer. Thank you for your explanations!