# Convert a ZF2 project to a git Repository

Tags: git, zend-framework2

i'm trying to convert an existing ZF2 application to a git repository , but when i do :

```
cd project
git init 
git add .
git commit -m 'init'
cd ..
git clone --bare -l project project.git
rm -rf mcoreg
git clone project.git project
cd project
git push -u origin master
```

i lost some files and repository ( containing library )  and the application fails.
i remarq that there are some files .gitignore and .gitmodules , i'm asking what should i do ? do i remove those files or what exactly can i do ?
Thanks for your help.
Merci.

Comment: "convert" ? You keep using this word, I do not think it means what you think it means. Does ZF2 provide version control features ?

Comment: For a good strategy to do version control using git on a ZF2 project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119810/how-can-should-zend-framework-2-be-included-to-a-git-versioned-project

Comment: i mean , i want to create a git repository from an existing ZF2 Project which contains already files ".gitignore and .gitmodules"

Comment: Why would it contain .gitignore and .gimodules files ? where did you get the code ? it is probably already in a git repository, in which case just clone it.

Comment: The .gitignore files lists all the patterns of files and directories that git will ignore (i.e: not version). Usually It is used to prevent the versionning of products (i.e : files that are generated at some point from the sources). The gitmodules file lists a series of submodules, which is a way to have several git repositories inside a top level git repository. This is by the way the strategy suggested by the question I linked.

Comment: we have get the skeleton from github.

Comment: so you cloned it ? `git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git`. If so you have a git repository... What is you problem ? Just change the remote. You have a working skeleton git repo. If you just want to clean up the history, this could be done I guess.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clear explanation... i 'll try now to correct the stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73320/discussion-between-felix-cantournet-and-user3911183).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that goes missing is the library information.
You will always have to run 

`composer update // php composer.phar update`

once you've checked out the repository on a new maschine.

The reasoning is that third-party-stuff isn't supposed to be inside the repository as this code shouldn't change anyways.

Comment: i did it , but i got errors :   [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not scan for classes inside "./Module.php" which does not appear to b  
  e a file nor a folder